# Query Optimization

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

I have 2 queries.

First:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE col='xyz' LIMIT 100
//Time Taken: 0.0047s
```

Second:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE col='xyz' ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 100
//Time Taken: 1.8208s
```

The second takes a much longer time. I know why that is, it is because first I have to select the whole table, then do the ordering, whereas the first query only returns the first 100 rows.

Is there any way to ORDER BY using another method, like selecting the last 100 rows and then doing the order? Or am I doing the query wrong and it can be made faster?

Note the Id is Autoincrement, so selecting the last rows will still return the correct data when it is ordered.

```
CREATE TABLE `table`(
    `Id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dateReg` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: Would it be fair to suggest, given you're using autoincrement on your id, you could just select the last 100 rows?

Comment: ^ yes but how do i select the last 100 rows

Comment: Post the result of EXPLAIN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for both queries, that will help. Also, what is "a much longer time"? How long does each query take?

Comment: Is your table `MyISAM` or `InnoDB`? Is `id` a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: Could you please post your *exact* table definition? Just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`table\`` and post the output.

Comment: That is, after you created the index.

Comment: Create table is up there

Comment: @ Quassanoi: Yes it was after i created the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For consecutive ids:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.id) 'maxid'
          FROM TABLE t) max ON t.id BETWEEN max.maxid-100 AND max.maxid
 WHERE t.col = 'xyz'
```

For non-consecutive ids:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rownum
          FROM TABLE t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
         WHERE t.col = 'xyz') a,
       (SELECT COUNT(t.*) 'max'
          FROM TABLE t
         WHERE t.col = 'xyz') m
WHERE a.rownum BETWEEN m.max-100 AND m.max
```

Comment: This however would not return the same results as the orginal query. When you want a particular number of records in a particuluar order, you need to apply the order by first. It appears the original poster doesn't care about that but someone else reading this later may not realize that the is a problem with this solution when you need the first hundred records in the order you askled for them.

Comment: Bit of a problem: My database is at work so i cant test it till i get there tomarow. However i will post the results as soon as i get it.... @HLGEM I have to order the last 100 rows. It is important to the design i have to display the last 100 rows that apeared in the database.

Comment: It's more of an academic curiosity for me - I prefer not to use subselects if I don't have to, but there's no alternative on mySQL (or Postgres for that matter).

Comment: i have the exact copy of what you have. And its not selecting the last. It selecting the first then sorting those. However if we can just select Last and then do the order the above will work a treat

Comment: @rexam You sexy SOB, seem to do the trick. :D....just as a side note what if id's are like this 200 199 198 190 189 185, Am i right in saying its not going to return 100 records.

Comment: @Shahmir: You awarded me the answer before I could post my non-consecutive ID solution.  Had to use non-ANSI joins in order to not have to use a SET command before the query to initialize the rownum value.

Answer (score 1):

Create a composite index on `(col, id)` if you're using `MyISAM` for your table.

In `InnoDB`, the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly included into your table as a row pointer, since `InnoDB` tables are index-organized by design.

In case of `InnoDB`, to make a composite index on `(col, id)` it is enough to create an index on `col` and make sure `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`.

This index will be used to filter on `col` and order by `id`.

The index is a `B-Tree` structure so it can iterate `ASC` and `DESC` with same efficiency.

Comment: A composite index might help but is there no way to just select the last 100 rows rather than the first 100 rows

Comment: `@Shahmir Javaid`: an index can work both ways with same efficiency. Just try it.

Comment: i will.. but will take some time as i have to repair table of a million records

Comment: Similar sort of times im afraid

Answer (score 0):

Your id column should be set as the primary key (or if you have some other primary key, you should put an index on it anyway). That should speed the query up quite enough.

Comment: It is indexed... same problem